# проблема с относительными путями в VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Подскажите, что можно сделать при такой странной проблеме:
vscode при html/css верстке не видит файлы css, лежащие в отдельной папке css. Не понимает относительные пути.
Пришлось все писать во встроенных стилях самой html.
Причем, эта проблема на домашнем компьютере не возникает, а только на работе, на одном компьютере.
В чем может быть причина? Что там не так? Что-то блокируется, как буд-то.
Верстку, сделанную на другом компьютере он понимает.
Но в нем самом если прописать такой же путь к файлу - не видит...

Comment: Ох бро !! Я столкнулся с такой же бедой !!! И не могу ее решить. Половина приложения была написана в раздельных файлах. А на второй пловине VSCode перестала даже в одной папке лежащие файлы связывать относительным путем.